# Gaïa utilitarianism?

Tags: utilitarianism

What is the name of the branch of utilitarianism that place nature, biodiversity, life on earth, maybe intelligence, at the center, like classical utilitarianism do with human ?

Comment: It is called non-anthropocentric environmental value theory. Thinkers who assign intrinsic value to non-human entities usually avoid the term "utilitarianism" due to the traditional association of utility with human centered value. See [Environmental Ethics from a Non-anthropocentric Point of View survey by Srivastava et al.](https://www.krishisanskriti.org/vol_image/07Sep201508091848.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Seems like a good starting point into the subject of environment ethics.